# Logic is failing After Successful run

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app workflow which is running successfully (Polling on premise DB). but after running successfully, it is keep on failed until restarted the IIS AppPool.

Can any one please let me know is there configuration change needs to be done ?
[image]

Below Code JSON snippet

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-04-01-preview/workflowdefinition.json#",

    "actions": {
        "SalesTransactionGPtoCanonical": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "InputXml": "@{triggerBody()?['OutputXml']}"
                },
                "method": "post",
                "queries": {
                    "mapName": "SalesTransaction_GP_to_Canonical"
                },
                "uri": "https://transformserviceaf6****************b4b6.azurewebsites.net:443/api/Transform"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "apiDefinitionUrl": "https://transformservice***************b4b6.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/1.0",
                "swaggerSource": "website"
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "type": "Http"
        }
    },
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {},
    "triggers": {
        "GetSalesTransactions": {
            "inputs": {
                "method": "get",
                "uri": "https://microsoftsqlconnector*************399.azurewebsites.net/api/xml/poll?triggerState=*"
            },
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Minute",
                "interval": 2
            },
            "type": "Http"
        }
    }
}
```

please let me know if there is any change in the JSON file

Comment: add some more info about the actions being configured in the LA, the input/output content which might have error in it.

Comment: Hi Tushar, please find the JSON script for the work flow and let me know if there is any change in the triggering section

Comment: @Vinoth, if you select any of the failed trigger executions in the ibiza portal, it will open up a blade with input/output/error details. This should help investigate why the trigger is failing

Comment: Hi, there is no error message. it simply says Bad Request. there is no information on input/output.Actually it is not failing. I am getting succeeded . but at the same time getting failed status also and continuously retrying around 5 times and failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the trigger mechanism by changing polling trigger to scheduled trigger and get the data from DB by using post method. now i am not getting failed message and working as expected

Thanks,
Vinoth

Comment: is this the full answer?

Comment: DB Polling trigger is getting failed even after successful run. but when I change the trigger mechanism to scheduled run and get the records using HTTP post method , that time it worked with out any issue. I am not sure how do do with sql polling option. but i changed the way to make it work